# Boot from USB freezes

Tags: boot, live-usb

I am a total beginner to both Linux and Ubuntu.

I have a netbook, an Acer Aspire One D255 with Windows 7.

I want to boot from USB (no cd-drive on netbook) to first try Ubuntu and perhaps install it if it works fine.

I created a bootable USB (as shown on the [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)) , with Ubuntu Netbook Remix (10.10)
I booted, and on startup, a purple screen with at the bottom a stickfigure in a circle and next it something (a harmonica? a chocolate bar? a strip of ram?) This shows for a second or 2, and then I get a black screen with a blinking cursor, and nothing happens after this.

Then, I created a bootable USB with the most recent desktop-version (11.04)
It boots, it gives me menu, but if I press a key, everything freezes.
When I don't press a key, it starts running from USB, and it does performs 2 loading steps and then noting... total freeze...

What is going on and what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
I tried waiting for 15 minutes but I still did not get a response.

> Loading /casper/vmlinuz/.......
>
> Loading /casper/initrd.lz............... ready.
>
> _(blinking cursor)

Comment: looks like there is little knowledge of the usb-issue , 'cause there are a fair amount of question rgarding usb-boot and most of them are unanswered.

Comment: looks like this is a similar problem: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/177132-ubuntu-live-usb-boot-problem.html

Comment: How long have you been waiting? Boot from USB can be slow.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: 5 minutes or so. Not long enough? Should I wait longer?

Comment: that chocolat bar is an accessibility icon :p It should bring you in a menu in which you can select accessibility options as well as other Live CD/USB tasks like RAM check. Some USB devices have a LED light to display activity, perhaps you're lucky too. Wait for about 15 minutes, it shouldn't take longer than that unless you've a USB 1.1 connector.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: ok thanx for your advice. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Can you try the usb drive in another machine? I suspect that it's something wrong with/in it.

Comment: @Javier Rivera: ok, I will try this.

Comment: @Javier Rivera: I don't have another computer that can boot from usb...

Comment: @Natrium: :(. There are some other options: try with another usb drive or another live-usb creator like unetbootin.

Comment: @Javier Rivera: I want to give that a try, but I didn't have the time up till now.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).